# How to detect global key sequence press in Qt?

Tags: c++, windows, qt

I want to detect whether a key sequence is pressed and want to perform certain task on that event in Qt. Currently I can detect keypresses for certain widgets but how to detect global keypresses. By global I mean that even if the application is minimized or hidden , it should detect key press.

I tried making an `eventFilter` for the application, by first overloading `QObject::eventFilter` like this:

```
bool GlobalEventFilter::eventFilter(QObject *Object, QEvent *Event)
{
  if (Event->type() == QEvent::KeyPress)
  {
    QKeyEvent *KeyEvent = (QKeyEvent*)Event;

    switch(KeyEvent->key())
    {
      case Qt::Key_F1:
        cout<<"F1 press detected"<<endl;
        return true;
      default:
        break;
    }
  }
  return QObject::eventFilter(Object,Event);
}
```

and then installing that object as the `eventFilter` for my application:

```
QApplication a(argc,argv);
a.installEventFilter(new GlobalEventFilter());
```

and I also tried the doing this:

```
QCoreApplication::instance()->installEventFilter(new GlobalEventFilter());
```

In both the cases I am able to detect key presses when my application window is open but it fails when window is minimized or hidden. How to solve this?

Comment: This question and answers is of much better quality than the linked one. I vote to re-open.

Comment: @Adrian I agree. I reopened this one and closed the other as a duplicate of this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See the documentation of [QKeyEvent](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/QKeyEvent.html#details):

> Key events are sent to the widget with keyboard input focus when keys are pressed or released.

That means, if you wish to use `QKeyEvent`, you need to have the keyboard focus. Filtering those events does not change this conceptually either. I am not sure where you got the filtering idea from.

You might want to look into alternative solutions, for instance how it is implemented in  kwin, etc. In general, be careful with this use case. It could do weird things without the end users noticing it.

You could take a look at this class:

[QxtGlobalShortcut Class Reference](http://libqxt.bitbucket.org/doc/tip/qxtglobalshortcut.html)

You could write something like this then:

#### main.cpp

```
#include <QxtGlobalShortcut>

#include <QApplication>
#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QDebug>

class MyGlobalShortcutHandler : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit MyGlobalShortcutHandler(QObject *parent = 0)
        : QObject(parent)
    {
        m_globalShortcut.setShortcut(QKeySequence("Ctrl+Shift+X"));
        m_globalShortcut.setEnabled(true);

        connect(&m_globalShortcut, SIGNAL(activated()), SLOT(handleGlobalShortcut()));
    }

public slots:
    void handleGlobalShortcut()
    {
        qDebug() << "Global shortcut handled";
    }

private:
    QxtGlobalShortcut m_globalShortcut;
};

#include "main.moc"

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    QApplication application(argc, argv);
    QMainWindow mainWindow;
    MyGlobalShortcutHandler myGlobalShortcut();
    mainWindow.show();
    return application.exec();
}
```

#### main.pro

```
TEMPLATE = app
TARGET = main
greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets
CONFIG += qxt
QXT = core gui
SOURCES += main.cpp
```

#### Build and Run

```
qmake-qt4 && make && ./main
```

This code should be working with Qt 4, at least. It prints out the debug statement for me. You could easily verify this on your end.

To get the libqxt library, please visit the following link:

http://dev.libqxt.org/libqxt/wiki/Home

Comment: I have seen many apps doing that. Its not so difficult task. In fact, I have done it before using WinApi.

Comment: I don't care whether it is QKeyEvent or anything else. I just want a Qt way of doing that if its possible. If not I will have to implement that using WinApi.

Comment: I am unable to download Qxt library. I keep getting this error: Rate limit for this resource has been exceeded.

Comment: @user221458: try http://dev.libqxt.org/libqxt/get/v0.6.2.tar.gz and decompress it with a total commander plugin or so. If you cannot manage that, I can repack it for you.

Comment: Can I use Qxt for a closed source commercial application? I read its license and I am confused. Can't I use it under LGPL license?

Comment: @user221458: `if you have a comercial version of Qt, you may use this library under the terms of LGPL.` from their [LICENSE file](http://dev.libqxt.org/libqxt/src/6106994dbf0269d0a32f3adad5effae8f98afa0f/LICENSE#cl-10).

Comment: No, I don't have a commercial version of Qt.I am using Qt under LGPL.

Comment: LGPL is a commercial version of Qt because it can be used in commercial applications just fine...

Answer (score 6):

This feature is not implemented in Qt. You can use [Qxt](http://dev.libqxt.org/libqxt/wiki/Home). Qxt is an extension library for Qt providing a suite of cross-platform utility classes to add functionality not readily available in Qt. It has Global Shortcut (hot keys) which detects key presses even if the application is minimized.

After compiling and linking your application to Qxt, you can include QxtGlobalShortcut:

```
#include <QxtGlobalShortcut>
```

Example usage:

```
QxtGlobalShortcut* shortcut = new QxtGlobalShortcut(window);
connect(shortcut, SIGNAL(activated()), window, SLOT(toggleVisibility()));
shortcut->setShortcut(QKeySequence("Ctrl+Shift+F12"));
```

Comment: Seems promising but I don't want to add an extra library to my project just to implement that.

Comment: I am unable to download Qxt from their site:
I get this error :Rate limit for this resource has been exceeded
when i try to open this link: http://dev.libqxt.org/libqxt/get/v0.6.2.zip

Are there any mirrors?

Comment: Some times i get the same error, some other times i can get it. Try to refresh the download link may be you could get it.

Comment: thanks for this answer I know it's been a long time on this question but asks may you help what if I want a mouse to click what I should write? and Thanks in advance