# C++/Qt Global Hotkeys

Tags: c++, qt, hotkeys

I'm working on an application, which I need to run in the background and run a function when a certain combination of buttons is pressed. I kind of understand that this requires a platform-specific API call (WIN32, X11, etc.), but I don't really know how to start. Also, is there a multi-platform way to achieve this? I really need this to work on Windows, Linux, and OSX.

Comment: Is that what you want?
[how-to-detect-global-key-sequence-press-in-qt](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23193038/how-to-detect-global-key-sequence-press-in-qt)?
maybe [this](https://github.com/falceeffect/UGlobalHotkey) worth to have a look as well.

Comment: @holzkohlengrill Yes. this seems to be what I am looking for. I have been trying to find something like this for days now. However, I can't find a way to get that library. It just redirects me to bitbucket.org

Comment: @holzkohlengrill I also just noticed that Qxt is no longer maintained. I will try with the second link (the library was last updated 21 days ago, so seems promising) you posted and report back.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To summarize:

1. [The Qt Event System](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/eventsandfilters.html) may be an option (with some help on system/desktop manager level)
2. [Qxt Library](http://libqxt.bitbucket.org/doc/) (not longer maintained)
3. Or this project [UGlobalHotkey](https://github.com/falceeffect/UGlobalHotkey)

.
2. seems the best option so far. Though it is not longer maintained it currently works with Qt5.

Comment: Qt's event system won't (by itself) do the trick, since it only handles events that are first delivered to it by the operating system.... and the operating system will not (by default) deliver keystrokes to an application whose windows don't currently have the focus.

Comment: Can I just include the header files of Qxt or UGlobalHotkey? Both show how to compile it, but not how to include it. Also, thank you for your suggestions

Comment: Have a look at their documentation. Just add the library to your project (qmake file) and use their library.
I just took an arbitrary [example](http://libqxt.bitbucket.org/doc/0.6/qxtbdbhash.html): includes, examples,... are all here.

Answer (score 5):

Take a look at https://github.com/kwhat/libuiohook

Its a c library that can easily be integrated with Qt.
Allows both global keyboard and mouse events listeners.

or

https://github.com/Skycoder42/QHotkey

This one is a Qt based library and seems to be maintained.

Answer (score 3):

http://amin-ahmadi.com/2015/11/14/how-to-use-system-wide-hotkeys-in-your-qt-application/ shows how to use the Windows API's [RegisterHotKey](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646309(v=vs.85).aspx) in Qt.

You'll need the key code(s) for your hotkey(s).

Comment: It works fine, but the menu bar and other things will no longer work. The nativeEvent will get all events and Qt won't receive them.