# overriding system-wide (Windows) key shortcuts in Qt app

Tags: windows, qt

`Ctrl+Escape` is a global Windows shortcut for opening main system menu. But I would like my Qt application to use this shortcut without triggering Windows main menu. I know it is probably a bad idea to override system shortcuts in general, but I would like to use this shortcut is a very limited use case.

This usecase is as follows. I have a popup window containing several rows or items. This window is opened by `Ctrl+Tab` and while the user holds `Ctrl` and keep pressing `Tab`, the current rows are cycled through. When the user releases `Ctrl`, the current row is used for some operation... But sometimes it happens that user presses `Ctrl+Tab` and then realizes he does not want to continue. He usually presses `Escape` while still holding `Ctrl`. And then it triggers Windows system menu and normal user gets confused, choleric user get angry... which is a bad thing. In other words I would like to be able to close the popup window when user presses `Ctrl+Escape`. How to do that? It is even possible?

If I write the code using this shortcut like any other short, it does not work and it always triggers Windows main menu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand it, Qt will typically not receive the key event if the underlying window system has intercepted it.  For example even QtCreator cannot override system-wide shortcuts.

This question is almost a duplicate of: [C++/Qt Global Hotkeys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35564502/c-qt-global-hotkeys)

While that question is asking specifically to capture shortcuts in a hidden/background application, I think the basic concept is the same -- capture shortcuts before the window system processes them.

From that answer, [UGlobalHotkey](https://github.com/falceeffect/UGlobalHotkey) seems pretty good, and the [How to use System-Wide Hotkeys in your Qt application](http://amin-ahmadi.com/2015/11/14/how-to-use-system-wide-hotkeys-in-your-qt-application/) blog post could be useful for your limited-use case (but read the comments on that blog post about fixing the example).

Also found:

- https://github.com/mitei/qglobalshortcut
- https://github.com/Skycoder42/QHotkey  (looks like a more detailed version of above)