# How to get glfw to register key events when window isn't focused

Tags: linux, glfw

I'm currently working on a multi-platform application, and the linux version uses glfw to handle input.

I need to be able to handle keystrokes (at least mod keys like ctrl and shift) when the window isn't focused, but I'm not seeing anything in the docs about this.

note: if the answer is "use something other than glfw", I'm open to suggestions as long as it works on the overwhelming majority of distros.

Comment: According to [this](https://github.com/glfw/glfw/issues/1204), I guess that seems to be impossible in glfw. If you are ok with a high-layer one like Qt, it should be possible. ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23193038/how-to-detect-global-key-sequence-press-in-qt)) But in that case, you are basically advised to make your app entirely with Qt.